# Best Way to Post URLs from Row to Column

Tags: excel

I have 50,000 URLs in 1 cell separated by spaces. How can I tell Excel to take each URL and put it in it's own column.

I've tried working with Text to Columns and then using Transpose but there aren't enough columns from left to right to handle 50,000 cells.

Comment: one way would be to replace every nth space with a | (pipe) and use the pipe as the delimiter to get the 50,000 down to more manageable chunks.   Rinse and repeat until you have one URL per cell...as you've discovered, it's going to take more than 1 row to get this done.

Comment: @sous2817 I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: @pnuts no it's greater than that of course - I can paste less than that if needed, what I'm looking for is just the most efficient was to get 50K urls into rows.

Comment: They are all in one cell.

Comment: What @pnuts is trying to say, is that the maximum amount of characters that can fit into a single cell in Excel is 32,767.  So even if you pasted your URLs into a single cell, it would only paste up to 32,767 total characters, leaving out thousands of the URLs.  You can't actually get all 50,000 URLs into a single cell because Excel's built-in limitations.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense - that's why I can enter less URLs in the cell but it would still be a lot of urls where the column length won't be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with VBA

sub ParseURLs()

```
dim vList as variant
dim sWS as worksheet
dim aCell as range
dim vItem as variant
dim lCol as long 
dim lRow as long 
lrow = 0
set sws = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
set aCell = sws.Range("A1")

'*** parse url list into an array
vlist = split(aCell, " ")
lcol = 1
for each vitem in vlist
  if vitem <> "" then
    acell.offset(lrow,lcol).value = vitem
    lcol = lcol + 1

    if lcol = 16384 then '*** total columns in excel
      lrow = lrow + 1
      lcol = 1
    endif
  endif
```

next vitem
end sub

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked and was a simple enough solution.